# Choose Correct Control (TabControl,ListView,ListBox,Button) - WPF Custom Style

Tags: wpf, styles

I want to create a theme like Apple Ipad in WPF,
if you know any , please let me know.
else, please help, to choose correct control for these Pictures in WPF (TabControl,ListView,ListBox,Button).

[image: Tab Like Buttons]
[image: Metro Like Buttons]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

as for the top picture, it makes sense to use a **TabControl** where you need to:

1. change the template/style of the **TabControl** to center the **TabItem** headers. you can change the panel to just a **StackPanel** with Horizontal orientation or a custom panel.
2. as for the TabItem controls, you make the round corners of the first and last items by setting the attached properties **IsFirst**, **IsLast** (you need to create them).

the attached properties can be set either automatically by the custom panel, or manually via xaml.

Regards